# How to use backbone in this context

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have this piece of code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('#result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});
```

where

```
data = "<p>Hello</p>"
```

Now let's suppose I would use to change this piece of code for use backbone and template

I will create a file myTemplate.html

```
<p>{{data}}</p>
```

and the response of the server will be `{data: "Hello"}` instead of `<p>Hello</p>`

Let's suppose I have also created my view/model and collection (`MyView`, `MyData`, `MyCollection`) using Backbone.

How should I modify my piece of ajax code?

Comment: If your ajax call is returning a collection of data then just add it to your collection in the success handler. I'm not sure I fully understand what your question is.

Comment: It can return data or collection of data. Can you provide me an example how can I edit my success handler?

Comment: You should have some knowledge of whether it's a collection or not before adding it to either. For example, if it's a collection (i.e. an array) then MyCollection.add(data); is all you need to put it in your collection. Bind a handler in your view for this event on your collection to a render call.

Comment: Can you make an example of binding a handler in my view for this event on my collection to a render call? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you should modify your ajax success handler in this way:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {

    // if data is not a collection 
    var myData = new MyData();
    myData.set(data);

    // if data is a collection 
    var myCollection = new MyCollection();
    myCollection.add(data);

    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});
```